# octave function how to isolate values and print them

Tags: function, octave

I have created the following function in octave. I input 2 integers and I want it to calculate what exists in the body of the function.

```
function [U, R, Q, X] = qsmd1(lambda, mu)
  U=lambda/mu;
  R=1/mu + U/(2*mu*(1-U));
  Q=U+(1/2)*(U^2/(1-U));
  X=Q/R;
  return;
endfunction
```

In the command line I write something like this

```
R=qsmd1(0,3)
disp(R); #print R
X=qsmd1(0,3)
disp(X);
```

However, each time I get the value of U. And not the unique value of R, Q, X that the function is called upon each time.
Thanks in advance

EDIT-SOLVED.
With the given answer I got below I found the solution on how to isolate each Value of the function's body. Here's how:

```
>> [U,R,Q,X]=qsmd1(5,2);
>> disp(U);
2.5000
```

or `R=qsmd1(0,3,'R')`
for example, as stated below

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is basic MATLAB syntax. Multiple output values are collected with `[U,R,Q,X]=qsmd1(0,3)`. They always appear in the same order as in the function declaration.

Comment: You're right, thanks for that. But is there any way to isolate the value you want each time? Given this syntax, when I run it, I get all the values together, at once.

Comment: You can ignore output values: `[~,R]=qsmd1(0,3)` or `[~,R,Q,~]=qsmd1(0,3)`. But the function will still compute them all unless you put specific logic inside the function to only compute what is requested. The easiest way to do this is by adding another parameter that specifies which output is desired: `R=qsmd1(0,3,'R')` (I like using strings as option arguments, standard MATLAB/Octave functions do this consistently too). The function then uses that value to determine which argument to compute. `function out=sqmd1(lambda,mu,which), if which=='R', ...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right. Also, I can do that which is correct >> [U,R,Q,X]=qsmd1(5,2);
>> disp(U);
2.5000